# Reading from a plist

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist

I'm trying to learn how to read from a plist... mine is a simple case.  I really just want to read one integer, although for a more general case of data I would appreciate advice as well.  The plist has Item0 - Array, and under that Item 0 with a number.  This is how I'm trying to read this.

```
plistArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/count.plist"]];


//count = [[plistArray objectAtIndex:0]];
count=(int)[plistArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"array %@\n",plistArray);

NSLog(@"count %i\n",count);
```

This is the plist xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
;<plist version="1.0"> 
    <dict> 
        <key>Item0</key> 
        <array> 
            <integer>12</integer> 
        </array> 
    </dict> 
</plist>
```

Comment: as it is... count is zero and array is nil in the log.

Comment: If the array prints nil, either the url is bad or the plist format is wrong.  Create the NSURL in a separate line (eg. `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString...`) before the `NSArray alloc` line and see if `url` comes out nil or not.  If url is ok, post the plist xml.  Also, NSArrays contain objects so the `count` assignment is wrong (int is a primitive type).  If the first item is an integer, it would be as an NSNumber object so you'd need to do `count = [(NSNumber *)[plistArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];`.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Item0</key>
 <array>
  <integer>12</integer>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: The url prints fine... so like you said it must be something with how I'm handling the plist. I pasted it in above... it looks kinda messy, but there is not much to it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the plist:

- the `;` in front of the `<plist>` tag should not be there
- the array you're trying to read in your code is inside a dictionary in the plist (the array is not the outermost element)

First, remove the semi-colon.

Next, either update the plist to contain only the `<array>` element or update the code to first read the `<dict>` and then take the `NSArray` from the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSArray *plistArray = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Item0"];

int count = [(NSNumber *)[plistArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your plist has a dictionary as the root object, not an array. You should be creating an NSDictionary with the contents of the URL, this will then contain an array (for key Item0) and the first object of *this* array will be your NSNumber holding the integer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're creating the plist, but I think you're saving an NSDictionary and not an NSArray.

The structure of the data in the plist shows that the root object is a dictionary (dict), which contains one key/value pair. The key is "Item0", and the value is the NSArray I think you're looking for.

Try this:

```
plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/count.plist"]];
NSArray * plistArray = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Item0"];
NSLog(@"array %@", plistArray);
```