# Get a string from an online Plist file?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, xcode, plist

I've never done any online things in an app before and have been searching google for the answer for the past 2 hours and nothing has worked.

Is there a very simple way to get a value (preferably a string) from an online plist file for iOS 6 in Xcode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098237/iphone-dev-strings-inside-arrays-of-plist-file

Comment: Hi, his Plist file is stored locally on the device. I want it to be on a server online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `initWithContentsOfFile`

Check these links out

[Reading from a plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102036/reading-from-a-plist)

[Read plist from URL into NSMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460550/read-plist-from-url-into-nsmutabledictionary)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could treat the content of plist file on server as String provider, fetch the data with `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error`, then parse NSString data as plist format,

```
NSString *plistDataString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain/test.plist"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSData* plistData = [plistDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary* plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];
NSLog( @"plist is %@", plist );
```

Comment: Thanks to you as well, because you helped with the encoding error I had.